# How likely is it for bubbles to form with spray-applied polyrethane compared to brush-applied?

Tags: polyurethane

I am thinking about applying polyurethane on my wood to protect it against moisture.  But I'm concerned about bubbles forming in the polyurethane.

I see why bubbles may form when applying polyurethane improperly when using a *brush*, but what I don't know is whether bubbles can form when applying the same by spraying.

***Question.*** How likely is it for bubbles to form with spray-applied polyurethane compared to brush-applied?

Comment: Bubbles are impossible when you spray finish. What type of poly do you use?

Comment: What are you finishing here? Spraycan versions of some common finishes can be a useful shortcut for some projects but this option is generally best kept for small items because you're paying a lot more for the finish in this form than just in a regular can, because of the (supposed) convenience and ease of application. Plus it's harder to get a uniform result on larger areas, as well as on some 3D shapes and complex surfaces because finish tends to build fast on raised areas and shies away from recesses and inside corners.

Comment: BTW what poly type are you intending to use here? If it's oil-based poly you can achieve a flawless finish without any great difficulty using the stuff in a can, because the application process can be changed so you *cannot* get bubbles. Bubbles are possible with oil-based varnish when applied conventionally, but this issue is much more pronounced with waterbased finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I see why bubbles may form when applying polyurethane improperly when using a brush

Bubbles can actually occur even with good application technique.

Obviously if bubbles are present in the finish to begin with they can be transferred to the surface — hence the very common "Do not shake" instruction on cans of finish — but even when the finish has zero bubbles in it initially bubbles can form during application.

This is due to turbulence caused by the drag of the application tool<sup>1</sup> over the surface; this is the *primary* cause of bubbles  (source: Bob Flexner).

Bubble formation and remaining bubbles after drying are much more of a problem with waterbased finishes than with oil-based varnish<sup>2</sup>.

> How likely is it for bubbles to form with spray-applied polyurethane compared to brush-applied?

Pretty unlikely! You'll notice, in contrast to the instructions on normal containers, spraycans instruct us to shake well ^_^

From this you can tell that bubbles are a non-issue with spray application. When sprayed a liquid is highly compressed and then converted to *tiny* droplets, which eliminates bubbles of any significant size.

---

<sup>1</sup> This includes natural and synthetic bristle brushes, foam brushes and even wiping rags. You can watch this process occur in front of your eyes next time you apply varnish or waterbased finish at anything other than a snail's pace.

<sup>2</sup> For a number of reasons, one of which is that oil-based varnishes usually dry much more slowly which gives time for bubbles to rise to the surface naturally and pop. Also oil-based varnish can safely be heavily diluted (e.g. when converted to wiping varnish) which eliminates the problem of bubbles nearly 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Usually sprayed on finishes are much smoother than brushed finishes, no matter what kind of finish you're applying, and I've never heard of bubbling being an issue with sprayed finishes.

Usually the issue you'll run into with a sprayed finish is getting runs because you've held the sprayer too close to the surface or moved too slowly thus applying the finish too thick.

So long as you do light coats, you should be very satisfied with a sprayed finish.

Note that this applies to both spray cans (rattle cans) or to finishes applied using spray equipment.

Answer (score 0):

Most problems with bubbles in poly comes from aeration of the poly in the container. If you take care to agitate the poly as little as possible when moving it from the housing to whatever container is used during application then the risk of bubbles is greatly reduced.

It is the polar opposite of certain oil finishes that need to be vigorously shaken before use.

Comment: *"The main cause, whether brushing or spraying, is too much turbulence during application,* much more so than from shaking or stirring the finish, *which are the causes that are usually cited. I remember being told many years ago that the way to avoid bubbles is to brush very slowly one foot every eight seconds. So I tried it, and it worked! But that’s no way to complete a project. Try it to see what I mean."* — Bob Flexner